# Passing values from jsp page to servlet through href

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I am stuck with this problem from last few hours. I am using Servlets and jsp pages. In the below code I used scriplet to use values passed to jsp page from servlet.

`display` is a string of array in the form of id, image-path, id2, imag-path2, id3, image-path3, id4 ......

I am using these images as a href. Now I need to pass id values to the href servlet.

Could you please suggest what is the best way I can achieve that?

```
<div class="get-images-class">
                <%
                   String[] display = (String[])request.getAttribute("images");
                   if (display != null && display.length != 0)
                   {
                        for(int i=0; i<display.length; i++)
                        {   out.println(display[i]);
                            i++;%>
                            <a href="ImageBrowseServlet"><img src="<%=display[i]%>" alt="image missing"></a>
                        <%}
                   }
                %>
            </div>
```

Comment: what type of data do you want to send from jsp to servlet??

Comment: it is string eg 173a

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam is it matter?you can cast the variable in servlet. problem solved. am i right?

Comment: yes its matter... Only String or Array of String??

Answer (score 2):

u can use **url passing parameters**

```
<a href="ImageBrowseServlet?val1=A&val2=B"> <img src="<%=display[i]%>" alt="image missing"> </a>
```

in servlet

```
String value1 =  req.getParameter("val1");
String value2 =  req.getParameter("val2");
```

Comment: yes it worked thanks.

Comment: your welcome@GagandeepSinghRandhawa

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the value in url parameter with servlet like-

```
<div class="get-images-class">
                <%
                   String[] display = (String[])request.getAttribute("images");
                   if (display != null && display.length != 0)
                   {
                        for(int i=0; i<display.length; i++)
                        {   out.println(display[i]);
                            i++;%>
                            <a href="ImageBrowseServlet?id=<%=display[i]%>"><img src="<%=display[i]%>" alt="image missing"></a>
                        <%}
                   }
                %>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<img src="ImageBrowseServlet?Id=<%=display[i]%>" alt="image missing">
```

assuming your servlet has parameter Id to receive sent value like this :-

```
String Id=request.getParameter("Id");
```